# Remove Event receiver in SharePoint Hosted App Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-hosted-app

Is it possible to create a remote event receiver in sharepoint hosted app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharePoint hosted apps dont support event handling as they are restricted to run javascript code only. In case of Remote event receiver it uses  CSOM code(managed CSOM or C# CSOM) to talk to SharePoint and handle the events.

RER depends on WCF endpoint to remotely (in app web) handle events raised via SharePoint like `-ed` & `-ing` events. This WCF endpoint has server side code(managed CSOM) which is not supported in SP hosted app.

[Handle events in SP Addins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220048.aspx)